# elpy/pyvenv: "JSON readtable error: 80"

Tags: python, elpy

Trying to use `elpy`, I cannot get to run neither `elpy-config` nor `pyvenv-workon` commands that I get this error message in the minibuffer.

Steps:

- open a python file
- `M-x pyvenv-workon RET dev RET` where `dev` is the name of my conda virtual environment
- get status message for a few seconds: `Elpy is updating the RPC virtualenv (’c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv’)`
- end with this message: `json-read: JSON readtable error: 80`

Same for trying `elpy-config`.
Note that I have either `eldoc error: (json-readtable-error 80)` or `json-read: JSON readtable error 80`, launching both commands.

```
Elpy is updating the RPC virtualenv (’c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv’)
json-read: JSON readtable error: 80
Elpy is updating the RPC virtualenv (’c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv’)
eldoc error: (json-readtable-error 80)
Elpy is updating the RPC virtualenv (’c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv’)
eldoc error: (json-readtable-error 80)
Elpy is updating the RPC virtualenv (’c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv’)
json-read: JSON readtable error: 80 [2 times]
```

I did not get any usable hint in the debugger (disclaimer: I am a newbie in emacs).
Researching, I understand the problem is in my python config, less likely on emacs config.
Any thought on how to further debug and solve? thanks.

**Emacs**: `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32)`

**Conda** virtual environment (trying to select as `pyvenv-workon`, unsuccesfully):

```
>> (dev) C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-28.1\bin>conda env export --from-history
name: dev
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip
  - pandas
  - ipython
  - jupyter
prefix: C:\Users\c740\miniconda3\envs\dev
```

Windows specs:

```
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎22/‎01/‎2023
OS build    22621.1105
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22638.1000.0
```

Resources consulted and somewhat related:

- https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9941
- https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/15026
- https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter/issues/301
- https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#installation
- https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/120

Appendix: complete conda environment packages list:

```
>> (dev) C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-28.1\bin>conda env export
name: dev
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyio=3.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - babel=2.11.0=py310haa95532_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1=py310haa95532_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h9128911_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h2bbff1b_1002
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.01.10=haa95532_0
  - certifi=2022.12.7=py310haa95532_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h2bbff1b_3
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py310haa95532_0
  - comm=0.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - cryptography=38.0.4=py310h21b164f_0
  - debugpy=1.5.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - flit-core=3.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - glib=2.69.1=h5dc1a3c_2
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.5=h9e645db_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.5=hd78058f_0
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - idna=3.4=py310haa95532_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=haa95532_3556
  - ipykernel=6.19.2=py310h9909e9c_0
  - ipython=8.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - ipywidgets=7.6.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310haa95532_1
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - jpeg=9e=h2bbff1b_0
  - json5=0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jsonschema=4.16.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py310haa95532_8
  - jupyter_client=7.4.8=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_console=6.4.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_core=5.1.1=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_server=1.23.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab=3.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.16.5=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - libclang=12.0.0=default_h627e005_2
  - libffi=3.4.2=hd77b12b_6
  - libiconv=1.16=h2bbff1b_2
  - libogg=1.3.5=h2bbff1b_1
  - libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=he774522_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - libxml2=2.9.14=h0ad7f3c_0
  - libxslt=1.1.35=h2bbff1b_0
  - lxml=4.9.1=py310h1985fb9_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310haa95532_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py310h2bbff1b_1000
  - mkl=2021.4.0=haa95532_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310ha0764ea_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - nbclassic=0.4.8=py310haa95532_0
  - nbclient=0.5.13=py310haa95532_0
  - nbconvert=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - nbformat=5.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.6=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook=6.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.2=py310haa95532_0
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310hd213c9f_0
  - numpy=1.23.5=py310h60c9a35_0
  - numpy-base=1.23.5=py310h04254f7_0
  - openssl=1.1.1s=h2bbff1b_0
  - packaging=22.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pandas=1.5.2=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pcre=8.45=hd77b12b_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pip=22.3.1=py310haa95532_0
  - platformdirs=2.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - ply=3.11=py310haa95532_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.36=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.36=hd3eb1b0_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pygments=2.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyrsistent=0.18.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - python=3.10.9=h966fe2a_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=py310haa95532_0
  - pytz=2022.7=py310haa95532_0
  - pywin32=305=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pywinpty=2.0.2=py310h5da7b33_0
  - pyzmq=23.2.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - qt-main=5.15.2=he8e5bd7_7
  - qt-webengine=5.15.9=hb9a9bb5_5
  - qtpy=2.2.0=py310haa95532_0
  - qtwebkit=5.212=h3ad3cdb_4
  - requests=2.28.1=py310haa95532_0
  - send2trash=1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - setuptools=65.6.3=py310haa95532_0
  - sip=6.6.2=py310hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py310haa95532_1
  - soupsieve=2.3.2.post1=py310haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.40.1=h2bbff1b_0
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - terminado=0.17.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tornado=6.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - typing-extensions=4.4.0=py310haa95532_0
  - typing_extensions=4.4.0=py310haa95532_0
  - tzdata=2022g=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=1.26.14=py310haa95532_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - websocket-client=0.58.0=py310haa95532_4
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py310haa95532_2
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - xz=5.2.10=h8cc25b3_1
  - zeromq=4.3.4=hd77b12b_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_0
  - zstd=1.5.2=h19a0ad4_0
  - pip:
      - bookmarks-parser==0.1.3
      - html5lib==1.1
      - qtconsole==5.4.0
      - webencodings==0.5.1
prefix: C:\Users\c740\miniconda3\envs\dev
```

*Update 2023-02-09*: without understanding the problem, the `init` setup below is creating a usable `elpy-config` and a working Python IDE. Trying to install `jedi` and run `jedi:install-server` still triggers the original error, so I have not done it.

I am now using the virtual environment `emacs` (created using `conda`) and using the python installed in that virtual environment. I am not using the Windows-installed Python.

Also, I had to install some modules used by `elpy`, like `flake8`, in a terminal, because `elpy` had permissions issue. `elpy` was diligent in notifying when such action was required, even generating the full command for the terminal.

```
(use-package elpy
  :init
  (elpy-enable)
  )
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
(setq elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path "C:/Users/c740/AppData/Roaming/elpy/rpc-venv")
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "c:/Users/c740/miniconda3/envs/emacs/python.exe")
(pyvenv-activate "c:/Users/c740/miniconda3/envs/emacs")
```

Comment: unfortunately i have no real advice for you. but i'd make sure all of your emacs packages are up-to-date. id also just start emacs from inside your activated venv, instead of trying to "switch" between them using emacs/elpy

Comment: thanks @nega, after some trials&errors I ended up with a working configuration, however without solving or understanding the original problem. I will edit my question with the working setup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the issue was that pyvenv does not use `python-shell-interpreter` on windows. It uses `pyvenv-virtualenvwrapper-python`. This also doesn't let you just specify `python`, it has to be the full path of your python executable (including the extension). After specifying the full path with unix-style separators this particular problem disappeared (in my case this was `"C:/Python311/pythonw.exe"`).

I was actually encountering this particular issue trying to setup of my elpy rpc environment.